# Naive Query on Developing a Mobile Application

Tags: android, objective-c, mobile

I have developed application for android based mobile using Java. I have tried developing apps for Windows based mobile phones using C# and heard about iOS that one would need to know Objective C.

Wondering if there is any way to have one language to develop an application that can run on all these platforms. I understand every operating system executes programs having different binaries that it execute. But just wondering if there is any common platform like JRE that is run on these mobile operating systems.

Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short of working with HTML mobile webapps, I reckon your closest bet to a common language between the 3 platforms would be C# using Mono.

Check out Mono for Android and MonoTouch for iOS both supported by the same company.

Whilst you could probably use the same language for your apps and even share internal APIs across the different platforms, you would still start to encounter differences in how the UI is handled on each of the platforms.

Answer (score 1):

There is a project: http://www.appcelerator.com/platform which can be used for writing apps for Android and iOS... But from my experience I can tell that this is good only for simple prototype apps. The more fancy app, the bigger issues you would have with it.